# Comparisons in switch cases, are they valid?

Tags: php, syntax, switch-statement

Thats the code:

```
switch (true)
{
  case (isset($_REQUEST['a']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['a']) && ($_REQUEST['a'] > 0)):
  case (isset($_REQUEST['b']) && is_string($_REQUEST['b']) && in_array($_REQUEST['b'], $barray)):
  case (isset($_REQUEST['c']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['c']) && ($_REQUEST['c'] > 0) && ($_REQUEST['c'] <= $cbase)):
    try { echo "Foo"; }
    catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
    break;
  default:
    echo "Bar"; break;
}
```

I'm wondering if these are allowed for use in switch cases?
Very soon I must use `switch` because of many comparisons and willing to try it. In this case 3rd `case` gives me always correct output, even when `$_REQUEST['c']` is bigger than `$cbase`, while should fall to `default` :|

Comment: Why not simply use an `if` statement rather than abusing `switch` and then having to ask if it's valid - the fact that you need to ask shows that it's a bad idea to use switch like this

Comment: Have you tried to run it and find out? In any case: yes, they are valid. They are used by some to make a large `if` structure easier to read. But, as @MarkBaker already said: they cause more confusion by the odd syntax than they avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is valid. Using `switch(TRUE)` enables you to have strict comparisons in a switch statement. check this examples:

Not typesafe:

```
$a = '1';
switch($a) {

    case 1 : 
        // do something (will get executed)
        break;

    case '1' : 
        // do something:
        break;

}
```

Better:

```
$a = '1';
switch(TRUE) {

    case $a === 1 : 
        // do something; (will not get executed)
        break;

    case $a === '1' : 
        // .. do something;
        break;

}
```

---

Also this usage allows for more complex `case` statements, like this:

```
switch(TRUE) {
    case strpos($input, 'a') === 0 :
        // do something
        break;
    case strpos($input, 'b') === 0 :
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: So they are valid, but see again the updated question. I think I'm missing out something :\

Comment: This depends on your application. I cannot say if your logic is correct. I can only say that the `switch` usage is well known. From my own experience I can say that the boolean logic in that cases statements is to complicated and unreadable.

Comment: The comparison in 3rd `case` is between pure integers, `10000 >= c > 0`

Comment: I'm accepting your answer cause you were right - my logic was bad. Falling through the cases means that they return `FALSE`, for which situation the player should add `case (!(isset ...))` :)